# Iterate through jquery selector

Tags: jquery, slider, iteration, selector

I have codes that I am sure are pretty redundant and I want to make it shorter and cleaner.

So I have a list of five domains that has a slider for each. I'm using the [Simple Slider](http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/) five times. I have this:

```
$("#domain-1").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
  alert(data.value);
  alert(data.ratio);
});

$("#domain-2").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
  alert(data.value);
  alert(data.ratio);
});

$("#domain-3").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
  alert(data.value);
  alert(data.ratio);
});

$("#domain-4").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
  alert(data.value);
  alert(data.ratio);
});

$("#domain-5").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
  alert(data.value);
  alert(data.ratio);
});
```

How do I simplify this so I don't have to repeat the codes? I have to use IDs cause each slider should be unique. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you give them a class so you can just bind to the class, instead of listing all the IDs?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)**](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$("#domain-1, #domain-2,#domain-3,#domain-4,#domain-5").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
  alert(data.value);
  alert(data.ratio);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a class to them all may work out easier.

```
$(".domains").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
    alert(data.value);
    alert(data.ratio);
 });
```